# Probability of scoring at least two 6 in 4 deliveries

Tags: probability

Suppose that the number of runs scored of a delivery is uniform in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ independent of what happens in other deliveries. Find the probability of hitting at least $2$ sixes while playing $4$ deliveries.

The probability of hitting a six in one delivery is $1/6$. The probability of not hitting a six in one delivery is $5/6$.

So the probability of hitting two six in four deliveries is $P(B(n,p)=K)= \binom{n}{k}.p^k.(1-p)^{n-k}$

$$\binom{4}{2}.({\frac{1}{6}})^{2}.({\frac{5}{6}})^{2}=\frac{25}{216}$$ And this answer is wrong given the correct answer is $\frac{19}{144}$ - how can I arrive at right answer, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem asks for *at least* $2$

Comment: FTR: this makes reference to [cricket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket), where you can score a max of six runs (usually) on a single delivery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You calculated the probability of hitting **exactly** $2$ sixes in four deliveries.  The question is asking for the probability of hitting **at least** $2$, so you must also calculate the probabilities of getting $3$ and $4$ out of four deliveries.

Answer (score -1):

$$\begin{aligned}
P(\text{at least 2 sixers})&=P(\text{2 sixers})+P(\text{3 sixers})+P(\text{4 sixers})\\
&=C^4_2 (\frac 16)^2 (\frac 56)^2 + C^4_3 (\frac16)^3 (\frac56)^1 + C^4_4 (\frac 16)^4 (\frac56)^0 \\
&=\frac{19}{144}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).